# Unable to resize the textarea height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I've noticed a strange bug while using a `textarea` in a my project.
At first I thought there was a problem in my code but then I was able to replicate that bug extracting the essenial in a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezsz8xr5/) .

**The problem is:**
If I change the height of the `textarea` by code without any interactions from the user before, the height get stuck at that size.
For example, if you click to the button *"Change size"* (in the jsfiddle above) and then try to resize back to the initial size using the element grip (at the bottom-right corner), you can't.  It's like if that new height is the new ''minimum allowed size'' of the `textarea`.

---

What am I doing wrong? what am I missing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here works in both chrome and firefox also

Comment: @ketan I noticed that in firefox works fine, but still exist in chromium. is it then a chrome/chromium bug? Is there a workaround to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**Height overrides min-height in Chrome.**

> In older versions of chrome there was no restriction.
>
> So if you use height min-height will be your height. So you need to
>   set min-height and max-height only. Height overrides min-height in
>   Chrome.

```
textarea{
  max-height: auto;
  min-height: 50px;
  resize: both;
}
```

Okay this solution works for me (*chrome Version 47.0.2526.111 m*):
https://jsfiddle.net/ezsz8xr5/9/

I found this interestining link: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94583

**Seems that it is a known issue.**

Comment: I'm using `Chromium Version 47.0.2526.73` on `Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)`. I changed the style.height because it's what the browser do when you manually move it with the grip

Comment: no it's still stuck, remember to do not manually resize with the grip before clicking the "Change size" button.

Comment: Try to use `el.style.setProperty('height', 50);`

Comment: oh, so it's a deep browser bug, that's shame. also tested the `setProperty`  but didn't fix.   Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been asked a while ago, but there's no good answer to it, and I found a solution.

What I found is that putting a % height for the textarea will not change it according to its parent.

If you put the rule `resize: vertical`, changing manually the height you'll notice that your browser will put the style.height in **pixels**.

So I tried putting `height: 150px` and it worked.

So here are two solutions :

1. First, put your textarea's height in **pixels**, not in percentage.

```css
parent {
    width: 150px;
}

parent textarea {
    height: 100%; /* not working ! */
}

/* Instead, do : */

/* css variable */
:host {
    --height: 150px;
}

parent {
    height: var(--height);
}

parent textarea {
    height: var(--height);
}
```

For a SCSS way :

```scss
parent {
    $height: 150px;

    height: $height;

    textarea {
        height: $height;
    }
}
```

1. Second, declare the textarea parent's display as **flex**, and without any additional rule, it will automatically resize your textarea. If it does not, then do this :

```css
parent {
    display: flex;
    /* if flex doesn't work by itself, add this + textarea rule : */
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

parent textarea {
    flex: 1; /* tells the textarea to fit all the free space it finds */
}
```

It seems like a browser issue yes, still not fixed in 2022, sadly. If it is intentional, then it's even not documented.

Hope this will help someone in the future.